# Generate self signed certs for connection between nginx and upstream server

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have to deploy a backend that wants to handle HTTPS on its own. 
The README of that backend provides the following command to generate a self signed cert:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -days 3650
```

That gives me a `tls.key` and `tls.crt` file. However, the NGINX guide at https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/ requires some more stuff which I don't have.

It would be awesome if someone could tell me how to generate all the certificate files I need so that NGINX can talk to the backend via SSL.

The outside facing SSL connection is covered by Lets Encrypt.

Comment: How's that a programming question?

Comment: `However, the NGINX guide at [...] requires some more stuff which I don't have.` Which stuff exactly? It only needs the `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate`.

Comment: @tkausl the guide mentions a client.pem, client.key, server.crt, server.key and trusted_ca_cert.crt. I only have the server.crt and server.key it seems. I don't get why I need the client stuff and where I get them from.

Comment: You don't need client certificates. You can use the self signed certificate you generated as the trusted ca certificate.

Comment: @tkausl I tried that right now but it doesn't work. Nginx returns 502 and the log says the handshake with the upstream server failed.

Comment: @emix I can show you tons of questions related to nginx and ssl, guess why those tags even exist here. So, how is your answer even related to my question?

Comment: @tkausl I followed https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309 to create a cacert and use it to sign a new server cert. then i used the cacert as the trusted cacert in the nginx config but there is no difference.

Comment: Mentioned Nginx doc uses mutual TLS - do you really want/need to use mutual TLS? Are sure that your backend is able to verify mutual TLS connection?